# SQL Server: Help optimize my query

Tags: sql-server

C# programmer here and I've been tasked to edit a lengthy SQL Server procedure in one of our legacy applications that needs to be as performance minded and efficient running as possible. I would appreciate some confirmation if my route is the best to take for the scenario at hand.

**SCENARIO**

It's an unorthodox one due to the design both code and DB wise by the original designers. For a search grid, I need to see if a "warranty doc" has been generated or not in the `tbl.docs` based on the option the user selects and the concatenation value of the string/word "Warranty" and the `tbl.warranty.warrantyId` value itself.

This value of 'Warranty' + `tbl.warranty.warrantyId` equals the `tbl.docs.name` column value and unfortunately appears my only way to join/link the two tables.

Warranty docs can be generated multiple times per warranty.

Parameter `@IsGenerated` is the user option the end-user will select to engage the filtering or not.

Here's some populated data for illustration:

`tbl.warranty`:

```
| warrantyId | name        | createdDate             | 
|------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| 456        | Warranty 1  | 2002-04-01 12:14:53.330 | 
| 1000       | Warranty 2  | 2002-04-01 12:14:53.327 | 
| 1701       | Warranty 3  | 2002-04-01 12:14:53.333 | 
| 2456       | Warranty 4  | 2002-04-01 12:14:53.327 | 
| 3556       | Warranty 5  | 2002-04-01 12:14:53.330 |
```

`tbl.docs`:

```
| docId      | name         | createdDate             | 
|------------|--------------|-------------------------|
| 1          | Warranty1000 | 2006-11-25 13:33:31.093 | 
| 2          | Warranty456  | 2015-02-11 13:33:31.100 | 
| 3          | Warranty1000 | 2012-05-17 13:33:31.097 | 
| 4          | Warranty1000 | 2017-01-11 13:33:31.097 | 
| 5          | Warranty1701 | 2017-03-14 13:33:31.100 |
| 6          | Warranty456  | 2017-03-15 13:33:31.100 |
```

So you can see:

- warrantyId 1000 has been generated three times
- warrantyId 456 has been generated twice
- warranties with warrantyIds 3556 and 2456 have not been generated at all, so on...

**DESIRED ACTION(s)/RESULT(s)**

User can choose not to select any filter options, [I need to display all the warranty records and the time generated (tbl.docs.createdDate), but return with a null tbl.docs.createdDate (generateddate if you will) if it hasn't ever been requested to generate, or the MOST RECENT record based on max tbl.docs.createdDate (generatedDate) if it has]

```
 | warrantyId | name         | generatedDate           |
 |------------|--------------|-------------------------|
 | 456        | Warranty 1   | 2017-03-15 13:33:31.100 |
 | 1000       | Warranty 2   | 2017-01-11 13:33:31.097 |
 | 1701       | Warranty 3   | 2017-03-14 13:33:31.100 |
 | 2456       | Warranty 4   | NULL                    |
 | 3556       | Warranty 5   | NULL                    |
```

User can filter on warranties that docs HAVE been generated for, [I need to display all the warranty records that have a doc generated record based on the string/word "Warranty" and the warrantyId equaling the docs.name value.  Warranties that have multiple docs generated, I need ONLY the most recent time generated record]

```
 | warrantyId | name         | generatedDate           | 
 |------------|--------------|-------------------------|
 | 456        | Warranty 1   | 2017-03-15 13:33:31.100 | 
 | 1000       | Warranty 2   | 2017-01-11 13:33:31.097 | 
 | 1701       | Warranty 3   | 2017-03-14 13:33:31.100 |
```

User can filter on warranties that docs HAVEN'T been generated for, [I need to display all the warranty records that haven't had a doc generated record based on the string/word "Warranty" and the warrantyId equaling docs.name]

```
 | warrantyId | name         | generatedDate           | 
 |------------|--------------|-------------------------|
 | 2456       | Warranty 4   | NULL                    | 
 | 3556       | Warranty 5   | NULL                    |
```

This is my stab at it. I figured creating a temp table based off the docs table and using that in my query is the best route for efficiency and not bogging this query down anymore than what already is.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpDocs') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #tmpDocs
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpDocs
(
    createdDate datetime not null,
    name varchar(30) not null
)

INSERT INTO #tmpDocs (createdDate, name)
    SELECT createdDate, name 
    FROM docs

DECLARE @IsGenerated BIT 
SET @IsGenerated = 0

SELECT 
    w.warrantyId, 
    w.name, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 d.createdDate 
     FROM #tmpDocs d 
     WHERE d.name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId) 
     ORDER BY d.createdDate DESC) AS [generatedDate] 
FROM 
    warranty w 
WHERE 
    (@IsGenerated IS NULL OR @IsGenerated = 0 
     OR EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM #tmpDocs d 
                WHERE d.name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId)))
                  AND (@IsGenerated IS NULL OR @IsGenerated = 1 OR 
                       NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                   FROM #tmpDocs d 
                                   WHERE d.name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId)
                      )
               )
      )
```

**EDITED -- ATTEMPT #2**

```
select 
    w.warrantyId, 
    w.name, 
    d.createdDate as [generatedDate] 
from warranty w 
left join #tmpDocs d 
    on d.name = concat('Warranty', w.warrantyId) 
    AND d.createdDate = (SELECT  top 1  d.createdDate 
                      FROM     #tmpDocs d 
                      WHERE d.name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId)
                      ORDER BY d.createdDate desc)
WHERE 
    (@IsGenerated IS NULL OR @IsGenerated = 0 
     OR EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM #tmpDocs d 
                WHERE d.name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId))
    )
    AND (@IsGenerated IS NULL OR @IsGenerated = 1 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM #tmpDocs d 
                    WHERE d.name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId)
        )
    )
group by w.warrantyId, d.createdDate, w.name
```

The execution times are the same though, I'm guessing because my small dataset I'm working with:

(5 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

(5 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Thanks so much for reading this and etc.  If there's an alternative route (not using CTE because this is only one simple aspect of the proc i'll be editing, I don't have the time to refactor the whole thing at the time), I'd be very open to hearing it.  The execution of this procedure cannot afford to get bogged down.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not optimal. If you have any power, best solution would be to update the doc table and add the warranty id as a separate column, same datatype as the warranty id of the warranty table. If that's not an option another solution would be to break out both queries (one for docs, and one for warranties) and have the application generate the IN clause to contain the doc names.

As for the filtering that would be better handled in the application code.

The following query will get you what you need, though not too sure on the performance without actually being able to run the query against the db myself.

```
SELECT 
    w.warrantyId, 
    MAX(w.name) as name, 
    MAX(d.createdDate) as generatedDate
FROM warranty w 
LEFT JOIN docs d on d.Name = CONCAT('Warranty', w.warrantyId)
GROUP BY w.warrantyId
```

Comment: I highly appreciate the response.  I cannot edit the structure of the table, as there are more than just warranty documents being generated and etc.  All of this filters through the stored proc, and editing the design/workflow of that via the application side would take it beyond the allotted time given for this project.  I basically am forced to work with the structure in place.

Comment: Not sure how many sp's you're working with, but the above query should get you the results you're looking for.

in your results were you looking for just the latest doc, or did you want to have one warranty per doc?

Comment: Also is it possible for you to modify indexes on the tables? you made no mention of those in the original question, and bad vs good index is usually the best place to start with optimization.

Comment: I tried to do a left join query, but I could not get it to work/return the result sets I was expecting when I factored in the filter logic. As far as indexes, I believe those are in place already.  And yes, I included in my question the scenarios and the result sets I'm expecting per scenario.  I only need the most recent record that the warranty was generated. Please review my question again, I explained it as best I could.

Comment: I'll be home soon, but you can add a group by warranty id then change the doc date to max(doc date)

Comment: Vee, please review my edit.  I did it with a left join and got it returning the results I'm expecting.  Execution times are the same though between the two queries.

Comment: Just updated my answer, Should be the results you are looking for. let me know if it differs.